# Why my initialized object of Log4Net have all levels properties as false?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I use Castle.Windsor and Log4Net for initialize my Logger.

My log4net.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
  <log4net>
  <appender name="AllMessagesFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <file value="Logs/Log.log" />
  <level value="ALL" />
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100000KB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d %identity [%t] %-5p %c{1}.%M %m%n" />
    <IgnoresException value="False" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="ErrorsOnlyFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <file value="Logs/Error.log" />
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100000KB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d %identity [%t] %-5p %c{1}.%M %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <priority value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="AllMessagesFile" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorsOnlyFile" />
</root>

</log4net>
</configuration>
```

My AssamblyInfo.cs have foolow row:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

In constructor of class I got object via Winsdor:

```
public class ACIStart
{
    private ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public ACIStart(ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
```

I don't have any exceptions, I just got a logger with all properties (IsDebbugEnabled, IsErrorEnabled ... ) as false.

My log no write anything to log file.

What could be the problem?

Comment: If you look at the [log4net documentation for assembly attributes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes) it says this: "Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net
to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the **calling assembly** 
to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and
certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you need to add the loglevel in you root node:

```
<root>
   <level value="DEBUG" />
   ...
```